# Java.lang.NumberFormatException error: empty string- Exchange Rate application

Tags: java, xml, parsing, netbeans, xml-parsing

I'm writing a program which gets daily exchange rates from http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml and saves them to the List. Here is my code:

```
public class ParseTheXml {

    private List<CurrencyPojo> currencyList;


    public void setCurrencyList(List<CurrencyPojo> currencyList) {
        this.currencyList = currencyList;
    }

    public List<CurrencyPojo> getCurrencyList() throws ParserConfigurationException {
        currencyList = new ArrayList<CurrencyPojo>();

        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            URL url = new URL("http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml");
            Document document = builder.parse(url.openStream());

            NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("Currency");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) { // döngü her currency türü için
                Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                CurrencyPojo currencyPojoObject = new CurrencyPojo(); 

                currencyPojoObject.setCrossOrder(Integer.parseInt(element.getAttribute("CrossOrder")));
                currencyPojoObject.setKod(element.getAttribute("Kod"));
                currencyPojoObject.setCurrenyCode(element.getAttribute("CurrencyCode"));

                currencyPojoObject.setUnit(Integer.parseInt(element.getElementsByTagName("Unit").item(0).getTextContent()));
                currencyPojoObject.setIsim(element.getElementsByTagName("Isim").item(0).getTextContent());
                currencyPojoObject.setCurrencyName(element.getElementsByTagName("CurrencyName").item(0).getTextContent());
                currencyPojoObject.setForexBuying(Double.parseDouble(element.getElementsByTagName("ForexBuying").item(0).getTextContent()));


       currencyPojoObject.setForexSelling(Double.parseDouble(element.getElementsByTagName("ForexSelling").item(0).getTextContent()));  //  Last 3 codes have Emppty String errors
                currencyPojoObject.setBanknoteBuying(Double.parseDouble(element.getElementsByTagName("BanknoteBuying").item(0).getTextContent()));
                currencyPojoObject.setBanknoteSelling(Double.parseDouble(element.getElementsByTagName("BanknoteSelling").item(0).getTextContent()));

                currencyList.add(currencyPojoObject);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return currencyList;
    }
```

On the part that getting ForexSelling, BanknoteBuying and Banknote Selling values,I get

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at javaxmlparseandshow.ParseTheXml.getCurrencyList(ParseTheXml.java:55)
    at javaxmlparseandshow.ParseTheXml.main(ParseTheXml.java:75)
```

Can someone help me to fix these? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer to [parseDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String))

Comment: When you take a look at the raw XML, some of node are quite empty sometimes, so yeah, you got a numberformatexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can set 0 to empty xml strings

```
private double parseDouble(String val){
    if(val== null || val.isEmpty()) 
        return 0.0;
    else
        return Double.parseDouble(val);
}
```

EX :

```
currencyPojoObject.setForexSelling(parseDouble(element.getElementsByTagName("ForexSelling").item(0).getTextContent()));
```

Answer (score 0):

AS I understand from error stacktrace, 
element.getElementsByTagName("ForexSelling") field has no data. The parser tries to convert empty data to string and throws error.
Look at the xml you must see the empty field.
As a solution I think you need to first check the data is empty or not:

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something on the lines of

```
String forexStr = element.getElementsByTagName("ForexSelling").item(0).getTextContent();
if( /* forexStr conforms to your criteria like, for example: !forexStr.equals("")*/){
    currencyPojoObject.setForexSelling(Double.parseDouble(forexStr); 
}
```

?

Comment: I didn't try that, my main problem was  I missed the XML's empty values like "HINESE RENMINBI", or "HINESE RENMINBI". 's Forex Selling, BanknoteBuying etc. So that was the problem, I generated the empty parts as 0.0, It solves the problem.